# For $a\in (0,1)$,$ \lim_{h\to 0^+} \int_h^{1-h} t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1} dt$ exists. Let the limit be $g(a)$. Then evaluate $g’(\frac 12)$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

$$g(a) = \int_0^1 t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}$$

$$g’(a) =0$$

The answer seems straightforward, but it doesn’t feel right, so I would like someone to reaffirm it so that i know this is the way to solve it

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that $g'(a) = 0$?

Comment: @MartinR the limits are constants

Comment: But $\int_0^1 t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$ does depend on $a$.

Comment: @MartinR I know, that’s why i asked it over here.

Comment: surprisingly this question was asked today https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912236/find-limit-of-mathop-lim-limits-h-to-0-int-limits-h1-h-t

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore  That question asks $g(a)$. This question asks $g'(a)$...so they are a  little different...

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I have successfully found $g(1/2)$ on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're familiar with Leibniz integral rule (of differentiating under the integral sign).

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^bf(x,t)dt = \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)dt $$

Apply this rule on your integral. I believe you will easily find your answer then.

**EDIT:**
Your hypothesis that $g'(a) = 0$ is unfounded. Please perform the calculation again. If you face the problem again, just comment below. I or somebody will surely post the complete solution.

**EDIT 2:**
$g'(a) = 0$ does hold true at $a  = \frac{1}{2}$, so your answer might be correct too.

**EDIT 3:**
Differentiating under the integral sign, we get
$$g'(a) = \int_0^1 -t^{-a}\log{(t)}(1-t)^{a-1}+(1-t)^{a-1}t^{-a}\log{(1-t)} dt$$

Put $a = \frac{1}{2}$ here. You get
$$g'(\frac{1}{2}) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log{(1-t)}-\log{t}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}dt$$

Let this eqn be e1.

Now, use the $a-x$ property in definite integration and replace $t$ by $1-t$ and you will get

$$g'(\frac{1}{2}) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log{(t)}-\log{(1-t)}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}} dt$$

Add them and I think you will get your answer. Please point out any mistake if you find.

Comment: I am familiar with that concept, which is what I applied to get 0. Ofc, I might have used it wrongly, hence my question on MSE. Could you lay down your working so i know what is wrong?

Comment: Well @Aditya $g'(\frac{1}{2})$ is indeed 0. But this does not hold true for $g'(a)$. As you must have seen, a special case occurs at a = $\frac{1}{2}$.  (-a = a-1). **If** your answer is wrong, perhaps the correct question is whose link Albus gave above. In that question $g(\frac{1}{2})$ is asked instead of $g'(\frac{1}{2})$. Please do see to that....

Comment: The link Albus gave is in fact a separate question, and I have already solved it on my own. The answer is 0 for the question I asked

Comment: Can you please write how $g’(1/2)=0$ if my method is wrong

Comment: With what variable did you differentiate with?

Comment: With respect to a. The derivative of $a^{x}$ wrt x is $a^{x}\log{a}$ and hence my solution...

Comment: Oh I wasn’t aware you were allowed to do that. Thanks!